# Как вычислить ctg (котангенс) на Pascal?

Tags: pascal

Как записать это выражение в Паскале?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `1 / tan(sqrt(x))`

Comment: Identifier not found "tan"

Comment: uses Math; // dobavit'

Comment: Почему-то разные результаты. Сравнивал с калькулятором.

Comment: @Alban А в каких единицах работаете на калькуляторе? Радианы, градусы, ...?

Comment: Уже дан ответ. Градусы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавьте в секцию `uses` модуль `Math`
2. Вычислите выражение под котангенсом - `sqrt(x)`
3. Вспомните, как относятся тангенс и котангенс, и получите - `1 / tan(sqrt(x))`
4. Если вам нужен ответ в градусах, то - `1 / tan(sqrt(x)) / PI * 180` *(т.к. все стандартные математические функции в программировании работают именно с радианами)*

Answer (score 1):

`1 / tan(sqrt(x))` это правильный вариант. Результаты отличаются из-за градусов/радианов. Необходимо перевести радианы в градусы (умножить на `180/PI`) или наоборот (умножить на `PI/180`)